# Background image is not loading from internet

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am new to coding and I'm trying to set an image as the background on my CSS page.  I can get the background to change colors, but when I try to use an actual image, nothing loads.

```css
#background-first-page {
  background-image: url ("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589401774008-64bcae0af959? 
 ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mjc3fHxzcHJpbmclMjBmbG93ZXJzfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb- 1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
 height: 100vh;
}

body {
  color: blue;
  font-family: 'Cormorant Infant', serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Infant:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid" id="background-first-page">
  <h1>Beckett Wedding</h1>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2"> <a href="thebrides.html"> The Brides </a> </div>
      <div class="col-2"> <a href="thebridalparty.html"> The Bridal Party </a> </div>
      <div class="col-2"> <a href="RSVP.html"> RSVP </a> </div>
      <div class="col-2"> <a href="Directions.html"> Directions </a> </div>
      <div class="col-2"> <a href="Details.html"> Details </a> </div>
      <div class="col-2"> <a href="Gifts.html"> Gifts </a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Vote to close**: Issue was cause by a typo

Answer (score 2):

Delete the whitespace between `url` and `("image-url");`.

Comment: Oh my goodness!  Such an easy fix.  Thank you!

Comment: Np, it happens to the best programmers too :)

Comment: Even though your anwser is solving the issue, you should have commented instead. Issues that are caused by a typo are a reason for closure and removal (needs improvement -> Community specific reason -> not reproduciable or caused by a typo). As such, such questions should not be anwsered but commented instead. Such question hold no value to the SO communtiy, they will be removed and points awarded by upvoting or marking as an anwser lost anyways.